# cp copies from hard drive to USB 3.0 stick with transfer speed below 1.7MB/s!

Tags: cp

Aspire One Cloudbook 14 (A01-431-C8G8)
Linux kernel 4.19
Debian 10

Hi: I have a USB 3.0 pendrive (stick) plugged into a USB 3.0 slot in the laptop. I copied (cp) all files in one of the laptop partitions to a partition in the stick. 'du -hs' said the files amounted to roughly 7GB. Now cp was 70m executing and then I aborted (too much time). This means a transfer speed below ~1.7MB/s. How can that be?

Comment: What write speed is your USB stick rated at? See https://usb.userbenchmark.com/ for example of similarly slow devices

Comment: In the chart I see the peak 4k-write rate is 1.3MB/s. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. Fancy writing and accepting your own answer? (You get points for that too)